# How to add an city name text field in wordpress comment section

Tags: wordpress

I need to add an extra text field to enter a city name in that text field in wordpress. And i need to display that particular city name in the comment list too. whether there is a solution for this one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: [Adding Custom Fields to WordPress Comment Forms?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1353/adding-custom-fields-to-wordpress-comment-forms)

And another awesome post on this: http://wpengineer.com/2214/adding-input-fields-to-the-comment-form/

Comment: U r welcome :). But can u please mark the question as "answered"